# Migrating WPF ComboBox source inside DataGrid rows from IEnumerable to ICollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a WPF DataGrid where I bind one property to a combobox.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Buildings" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowStyle="{StaticResource DefaultRowStyle}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="#" Binding="{Binding Id}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Beschreibung" Binding="{Binding Description}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Building">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.BuildingTypes, ElementName=Root}" SelectedValue="{Binding BuildingId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I am using the element *Root* to get to the DataContext of my view model from the template.

This all worked fine, `BuildingTypes` was an `IEnumerable<MyBuildingObj>`.

Then I wanted some filtering and sorting for the combobox values. So I changed `BuildingTypes` in my viewmodel to serve `ICollectionView` instead of the IEnumerable. I ended up with this code:

```
public ICollectionView BuildingTypes
{
    get
    {
        var c = new CollectionViewSource();
        c.Source = masterData.Buildings.Values;
        c.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("Name", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        c.Filter += (sender, a) =>
        {
            if (this.Region == RegionType.None) return;
            var bt = a.Item as BuildingType;
            if (bt == null) return;
            a.Accepted = bt.Region == this.Region;
        };
        return c.View;
    }
}
```

When reusing the view, all comboboxes have the same value when selecting something suddenly so I now created a new view every time the property gets fetched - but it does not feel right.

Is this is correct way to provide a shared value source for comboboxes for each DataGrid rows but of course where every row can have a different value?

Is this the correct way to migrate a Combobox datasource from `IEnumerable<T>` to `ICollectionView` without leaking memory?

Comment: Collection view is relatively slow for filter and sort. That might not matter if the collection isn't very big or you don't have many rows.

Comment: Data size is like 200 records to select from, so not really heavy data.